# Dockerfile getting stuck while installing Apache2

Tags: docker, apache, dockerfile, apache2, devops

I was trying to create a Dockerfile for installing Apache2 on an Ubuntu base image and running Apache2 automatically when the container starts. Here are the instructions I wrote in it:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update; \
apt install apache2 -y

EXPOSE 80

CMD [“service”, “apache2”, “start”]
```

But, while installing, Apache2 is asking for geographic area and time zone and Dockerfile is getting stuck. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Why not just use an image with apache http installed, as this is the recommended practice.

Comment: @Diya' this was an assignment in a course and it was mentioned to use ubuntu as base image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` before the command.

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update; \
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install apache2 -y

EXPOSE 80

CMD [“service”, “apache2”, “start”]
```

check this to learn more  https://askubuntu.com/questions/972516/debian-frontend-environment-variable

Comment: thank you it worked.
But, I tired

`sudo docker build -t img:1.0 .`
`sudo docker run -it -p 80:80 img:1.0`

and am not able to view the apache page on 80 port. Can you help me with this?

Comment: your container will exit as soon "service apache2 start" is complete.

Comment: as per what the docker docs says a container is just a process which runs on a host, when the command is complete the container will exit.

Comment: so use CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]